# What does a Weapons Technologist do?

Tags: x-rebirth

So I was travelling around, and I came across a person with the same symbol as an Engineer but he was titled as a Weapons Technologist. I noticed that I could hire him.

What is a Weapons Technologist? What does he do?

Comment: better question, what do any of the NPCs do?

Comment: @spartacus Give Egosoft the false impression that they have created a more "human" experience... I was told we would be spending almost every second talking to our co-pilot INSTEAD of menus.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A **Weapons Technologist** is employed on a station to monitor and improve the efficiency of technical production processes using various technical components. Products improved by their services include: Missiles, EM-Spectrometer, Scanning Array and Warheads.

http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=347620